# MongoDB subtraction between two fields' values

Tags: mongodb

I need your help to do subtraction between the same fields in the same collection but in different documents.

I have `myCollection` like this:

```js
{
   _id: ObjectId ()
    Y: "2013"
    YMD: "2013-01-01"
    val1: 500
}
// ...
{

    _id: ObjectId ()
    Y: "2013"
    YMD: "2014-01-31"
    val1: 1000
}
// ...
{
    _id: ObjectId ()
    Y: "2014"
    YMD: "2015-02-01"
    val1: 1100
}
// ...
{
    _id: ObjectId ()
    Y: "2014"
    YMD: "2015-02-28"
    val1: 3000
}
```

What I want is a query that gives me this:

```js
{
    _id: ObjectId ()
    YM: "2013-01"
    val1: 500  //1000-500
}
{
    _id: ObjectId ()
    YM: "2013-02"
    val1: 1900 //3000-1100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a $subract operator in the aggregation framework.

First you'll want to use $group to group up by month, but I think you'll need to store month on your document to do that.